# What is file structure of AUTOSAR based MCAL module?

Tags: c, device-driver, autosar

What are all .c and .h files a MCAL module (eg. Lin diver, CAN driver) should contain? and what each of those files contain? How to derive configurations for them?

Comment: Autosar concept implies that you get your MCAL from one of many suitable suppliers. So without more information on which supplier you have, we cannot tell you. AUTOSAR standard also implies a rather complex, very indirect concept of modelling (in some six layers of abstraction), configuring a specific system, very completely and then generating code for the final implementation of said system. There are even (intentionally) different possibilities of storing models and configurations. Usually, an MCAL supplier also provides a tool for modelling, for configuring and for generating. Maybe same.

Answer (score 1):

That is not entirely specified by Autosar. The standard goes into great detail when it comes to behaviour of the implementation, but not into so much detail when it comes to files. There are many companies supplying MCALs, and each of those suppliers will make some decisions about code organization.

File names are actually specified though. The CAN driver has `Can.c`, `Can.h`, `Can_Cfg.h` and `Can_PBcfg.c`. By Autosar convention, the post-build part of the configuration goes to `Can_PBcfg.c`, the compile-time config is in `Can_Cfg.h`. Their content is mostly left to the supplier. `Can.c` is the implementation, `Can.h` is the header file for which no additional rules are given except that it shall include `ComStack_Types.h` and `Can_GeneralTypes.h`.

The configuration that gets generated is not entirely specified either. The input to the driver configuration is the ECU configuration (described in a chapter called "Configuration specification" for each driver or module), the output is mostly up to the supplier. The supplier may add additional layers of abstraction, may have their `Can.c` call functions that are in other, supplier-specific C files, and so on. You can be sure that `Can.c` is going to have the `Can_Write` function, but the implementation will be different for different suppliers.

MCAL suppliers will usually provide additional documentation for configuring the modules, and will either have their own Autosar configuration tool or recommend a tool that their MCAL is known to work with.

Answer (score 0):

see also standard/AUTOSAR_BSWGeneral.pdf

Can.c - Implementation of the CAN Driver .. could be split in other C files

Can.h - define the CAN Driver public interface as defined by AUTOSAR

Can_Irq.c - ISRs of the CAN

Can_Cfg.c - PreCompile Config e.g. CONST(CanConfigType, CAN_CONFIG_DATA) 
CanConfig = {...}   -- AUTOSAR allows to skip this file and put this config in LCfg or PBcfg files

Can_Cfg.h - PreCompile Config and Compiler Switches

Can_PBcfg.c - POSTBUILD_CONFIG  replaces the PRECOMPILE Config e.g. CONST(CanConfigType, CONFIG_DATA) CanConfigSets = { N, { CfgSet0 }, {CfgSet1 } ..}

Can_PBcfg.h - POSTBUILD_CONFIG  types, structures/defines

Can_Lcfg.c - LINKTIME_CONFIG configuration

Can_Lcfg.h - LINKTIME_CONFIG types/structures/defines

in case CAN Driver would provide callbacks for other modules to include:
Can_Cbk.h